# Destiny freezes and returns to beginning of campaign

Tags: destiny

I bought *Destiny* for PS3 at GameStop, and every time I get to a certain part in the single-player campaign (when the robot wakes you up and then you explore the building right before you find a weapon), it freezes. If I wait for a while after it freezes, it returns me to the beginning of the campaign (when the "background story" is told).

Is there anything I can do? I tried to wait a while and then play (thinking it was the server) but it always freezes at the same part.

Comment: How does it crash?  Does the system freeze?  Does it kick you back to the XMB?  Is the disk free of scratches?  Right where is the crash?  In multiplayer?  Single player campaign?

Comment: It freezes for a while and then begins the story again (single player campaign) its when the robot wakes you up and then you explore the building right before you find a weapon. I didn't see any serious scratching on the disk which is why I'm confused

Comment: @user9139 Just to clarify, when you say "It freezes for a while and then begins the story again", do you mean that you're immediately taken from the frozen screen to start of a new single player campaign? No black screen in between the two? Are you ever booted out to the PS3 XMB (like Frank asked)? For it to freeze and then restart the campaign seems really odd (but not impossible).

Comment: You know how when you first start the game they tell you the background story, then the robot wakes you up? It goes back to the beginning of the background story. I don't have to do the character creation again though and it doesn't take me back to the XMB screen. Its the weirdest thing.

Comment: @user9139 Hmmm, that does sound very odd. Thanks for clarifying. Even though this is a really odd bug, it still involves a freeze, so I would initially troubleshoot by trying the general purpose "fixes" for freezes. Clear cache, and free up some storage space (if you're running low) on the console. I forget how PS3 game discs work, but if there's a delete/uninstall option for the game, I would try "uninstalling" and "reinstalling" if possible.

Comment: I know my storage is great, but I'll try the uninstalling and reinstalling it. Thanks!